# Prevent duplicated ID on MySQL (InnoDB) across 2 tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Is it possible to have the ID of the next generated row (across 2 tables) be unique?

I have 4 tables:

- 1 for teachers
- 1 for students
- 1 for projects
- 1 for relations

The *relations* table has 3 foreign keys.
One refers to teachers IDs, one to students IDs and the other to projects IDs

Since a project can be related to teachers but also students at the same time, how do I make sure that a new created teacher or student won't have an ID already used by the other type of account?

If I can do that, then the relations table would have only 3 columns:
ID, project_ID and related_to(ID)

If not, I would have to add a 4th row indicating the type of account that it relates to (student or teacher).

Thanks for your help!

Regarding the difference between account types:
I have to translate this exact same situation to another project of mine in which the first two tables are completely different. That's why I don't bother to merge the students and teachers tables here.

Comment: Is there much difference in the dataset between "teachers" and "student"?

Comment: Not right now, but there will probably be another table which will be completely different from those.

Comment: This is not an answer, just a sugestion:
Tables: People,students,teachers,projects,relations
foreign keys
students link to people id
teachers link to people id
relations link to people id and project id.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have unique values between the `student` and `teacher` tables because the relation table has separate fields for each relationship, so there is no conflict.

However, this is not the right way to do things. You need two relation tables, `teacher_project` and `student_project`.  Alternatively, depending on the unique data that's different between teachers and students, you could have a single `person` table and a single relationship, which is probably closer to the real world anyway.

Comment: Thanks for you anwer Jim. I wrote the question completely wrong (because there are actually 4 tables, not 3). I carried the error and told the rest wrong too. I have now edited the question to reflect the real scenario.

Comment: Thanks again Jim. I need to translate this same logic to another project, where the 2 types of accounts are different (one is persons, the other is groups of persons) so in that case I wouldn't be able to merge them. Could you give me a pointer on where to ivnestigate about your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can identify the teachers begin with 1 ,incremental 2; the students begin with 2 ,incremental 2.By this way,odd number refers to  teacher while even number refers to student.No conflict will happen.